# Error while fetching default path Json for Google Credentials

Tags: c#, google-api, ocr, google-vision

**Error log :**

> InnerException:System.InvalidOperationException: Error reading
>   credential file from location OCR-c812724b.json: Could not
>   find file 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\OCR-c812724b.json'.
>   Please check the value of the Environment Variable
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.d__11.MoveNext()

**Below is my .cs Code**

```
Response.Write("<BR>GCLOUD_PROJECT:" + 
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GCLOUD_PROJECT"));
Response.Write("<BR>GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:" + 
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));
string[] delimiters = new string[] { "\n" };

var credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(); <-- Error here
Response.Write("<BR>Test for credentials" + credential);
```

Does anybody have as solution?

Comment: did you set your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable?

Comment: Yes it is set in Environment variable. @TorryYang